# XML Schema Definition (XSD) for XML files

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-signature, xsi, xmlschema

How can I check whether a XML file uses a XML Schema Definition (XSD)? For example, if you decompress a signed odt file (LibreOffice or OpenOffice text document), in the directory META-INF is the signaturefile *documentsignatures.xml*.
In this file the attribute `xmlns` defines a default namespace for the elements `<Signature>` and `<document-signatures>`. There is neither a reference by the attribute `xmlns:xsi` to the XML Schema Instance (XSI) namespace `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` nor a reference by the attribute `xsi:schemaLocation` to the XML schema file `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd`. As a result, the entire content of the documentsignatures.xml file should not be validated under any scheme. Is that correct?

Here are the first lines of the correspnding XML document *documentsignatures.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document-signatures xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:digitalsignature:1.0">
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="ID_006900630020002d0084000e004a008b009b00a6006f004b007c007b002d007f">
        <SignedInfo>...
```

Greetings

Kaleun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"...How can I check whether a XML file uses a XML Schema Definition (XSD)?..."*

(1) You cannot, if there is no embedded reference in an XML file by the attribute `xsi:schemaLocation` to the XML schema.

(2) Though, whatever API is in use, it can still validate against some XSD schema that is not mentioned in the actual XML file.

Comment: That helped me a lot, thanks :)
I took a closer look at [xmldsig-core-schema.xsd](http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#). Pretty much at the beginning (in the 12th line) is written down:
```<element ref="ds:KeyInfo" minOccurs="0"/>```.
Since ```maxOccurs``` is not specified, this value is set to 1 by default, which means that the ```<KeyInfo>``` element may only appear once. If I now copy the complete ```<KeyInfo>``` element behind it and I check the signature, it will be invalid. Could this be taken as an indication that the file _documentsignatures.xml_ is validated under a schema?

Comment: Instead of guessing, you can try to validate the XML file in question against the XSD by following (2) approach.

Comment: Yes, I can check that. But then I still don't know whether the ODF implementations LibreOffice or OpenOffice use an XSD. I get the indication that the signature is invalid by using LibreOffice or OpenOffice.